# 256-color chart for mode 13h?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bios

I am working on a small project, and am trying to match some colors I found on the web. Is there a 256-color chart for mode 13h available to do this? I can't seem to find one on Google.

Example of color code:

```
0fh ;white
0ah ;light green
```

**Final:**

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/VGA_palette.svg
[image: vga color pallete]

Comment: Search for "vga palette" on google images. You can also define you own palette by writing to ports 0x3C8 and 0x3C9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The palette you've got is *not* the default [mode 0x13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h) palette. It's a custom palette, that values 0 .. 0xff map to. Presumably for the best possible match with the game's artwork. Another example of the default [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/VGA_palette.svg).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.
Wikipedia on web colors
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcolors)
Good luck.